# How do I assign JSON Data to an instance variable?

Tags: swift

```
getTotals { (total, error) in
    self.totals = total
    print(self.totals)
}
print(totals)
```

In a function I am trying to do an API Request and assign the parsed data to a global variable. However, the print statement shows the value of the global variable inside of the function, but outside of it, it doesn't show. How can I get the data to the global variable so I can display it on other VCs or send it to a cell?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: [programmingios.net/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code](http://www.programmingios.net/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code)

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Answer (score 0):

it's GCD issue, 
you are trying to access to the variable before its initialization, the api request take a few Millisecond while the request   are under the processing the compiler is move on to the next function to execute so maybe you can use didSet on the variable  to declare your action, 
this article will help you to understand  property observing. 
https://medium.com/the-andela-way/property-observers-didset-and-willset-in-swift-4-c3730f26b1e9